# How to establish serial connection with Bluetooth device on Win7

Tags: python, bluetooth, windows-7-x64

I am really frustrated and have no idea where to search for an answer.
Currently I am working on a project to detect drowsiness with an ECG device ([Zephyr Bioharness 3](https://www.zephyranywhere.com/products/bioharness-3)). The device works but I can't find it with windows ([For example like this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/15290/windows-connect-bluetooth-device)). I tried several things:

- Find the device with my Smartphone -> works
- Find the device with an Ubuntu on the same Laptop -> works
- Connect directly on Win7 via Bluetooth with this Python Script: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/darkopetrovic/2127217) -> connects and sends data
- Find other Bluetooth devices with my Laptop on Win7 -> Bluetooth radio is dound
- COM port for (virtual) serial connection to a bluetooth device (device manager)

What I am trying, is getting this script to work: [ZephyrApp](https://github.com/darkopetrovic/ZephyrApp). Beside some compatibility problems with `QT` and `serial` (which I was able to fix), the programm hangs here [protocol.py](https://github.com/darkopetrovic/ZephyrApp/blob/master/zephyr/protocol.py#L49). I suspect the problems of not finding the device relates to the problems with the program. I know this is very special case, but hope anyone has an idea, how to fix this.

Regards,
paul

EDIT: Another PC with Win7 can't detect the device as well, it seems it is a Windows problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The device can't be detected with Win7, but I found a way to connect via bluetooth directly: https://gist.github.com/darkopetrovic/2127217